# How do I rearrange menu bar options in Qt Designer 5?

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I have been unable to figure out how to easily rearrange the menu bar selections that I have created in Qt Designer. Older documentation indicates that I can press the left click mouse button on a selection and then drag and drop it into a new location but this feature does not seem to work in this version.

I am trying to move "Load Database" above the "Exit" option. I would imagine I could just delete the "Exit" menu selection and add it again but I was hoping there would be an easier option in case this happens again.

[image: Full screenshot of my workspace]
[image: Screen of the menu items that I'm trying to move]

Comment: in the editor: you can just a drag and drop to re arrange them :)

Comment: I am assuming you are referring to Object Inspector or Action Editor? That does not work for me. I'm using Qt Designer in Windows 10. I have heard replies from others that what you describe works in linux versions. If you are referring to the editor in the screen shot that I provided - that does not work either.

Answer (score 2):

To do so you need to go in the ui editor.
Then click on File. Press and hold on the item you want to move. Move it.
Below you can see the exact same thing done in QT 4.12.3 and Window 10.

Press file

[image]

Press and hold on the desired item

[image]

Drag the selected item where you want

[image]

Now the 'Save as' is above 'Save'

[image]

Comment: I am doing exactly that what you described. It does not work in Qt Designer 5.15.0. At this point, it appears this must be a bug or error.

Answer (score 1):

Select your action in Designer
Press Ctrl + Up/Down

Comment: Unlike other answers, this is working for me in Qt Designer 10.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + Up/Down is working for me (Qt desinger 5.15.0)

Answer (score 0):

The bug is still present in Qt Creator v10.0.0.

A workaround is to edit the `.ui` file with a text editor (Qt Creator doesn't allow this), search for "<addaction" and rearrange the lines in the order you want the menu items to appear.